# read: read error: 0: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: bash, unix

I am running a bash script which reads certain values from STDIN. I have seen several folks hit the same error without any clear resolution or a resolution that worked for me.

```
 set -x 

 ./.clean

 { set +x; } 2> /dev/null

 read -p "Avoid using a public cloud:  [yn]? " avoidloud
```

The above read command gives a

```
 read: read error: 0: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Any help is appreciated.

Re-directing did not help either.

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: *What* your stdin is at the time of the error, and how it was established, is a critical detail entirely missing from this question. Please try to generate a [mcve], the shortest possible code that does everything necessary to let someone else see the error themselves.

Comment: (By "what your stdin is", I mean -- is `/dev/stdin` attached to a TTY? A PTY? A socket? A FIFO? Which specific *kind* of socket or FIFO? Etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this for redirection?

```
exec 3<&0 </dev/null
read -r avoidloud<&3
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the way could be to read directly from tty:

```
read -p "Your prompt " </dev/tty
```

instead of:

```
read -p "Your prompt "
```

In a similar case, it worked for me.